# ArrayAdapter not auto-refreshing

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom arrayadapter and as new data comes in the listview keeps growing. But, as I add new data to the underlying adapter using adapter.add and then calling notifyDataSetChanged(), the adapter gets updated but it does not auto-refresh like I was expecting. It only refreshes when I try to scroll. I want the listview to auto-refresh. I have been looking everywhere and it tells me to use notifysetdatachanged. Where did I go wrong?

Below is my code:

```
class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.chat_list, messages);
    }

   //        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ArrayList<String> messages, ViewGroup parent) {
         final Viewholder viewholder;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list, parent, false);
            viewholder = new Viewholder();
            viewholder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
        }
        else {
            viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewholder.message.setText(chat.messages.get(position).toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

}
static class Viewholder
{
    TextView message;
}
```

Another snippet where I call the datachanged:

```
Message new_message = (Message) packet;
                 if(new_message.getBody() != null)
                 {
                     Log.v("LogCat", "Message Received from " + new_message.getFrom() + " and as " + new_message.getBody());

                     messages.add("From: " + new_message.getFrom().toString());
                     messages.add(new_message.getBody());

                     myadapter.add(new_message.getFrom().toString());  // i also tried to disable this.. dint work
                     myadapter.add(new_message.getBody());


                     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                         }
                     });
                 }
             }
```

Comment: `ArrayAdapter#add` already calls `notifyDataSetChanged`, there is no need for that, you can disable this by calling `ArrayAdapter#setNotifyOnChange`

Comment: Thank you.. i will remove that line. But what about the auto-refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Array Adapter, when you add an object using add() of Array Adapter it adds the Object at the end of the Array, so you will have to scroll to the end of the List to see the new Data on List View, You can use something like this

> `mListView.smoothScrollToPosition (mAdatper.getCount() - 1)`

To programmatically scroll to the end of the List View to see the new Data added.

Comment: I start with zero items in the list view.. I just tried your answer  but it doesnt do anything either.. I have to manually refresh the listview by touching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might stumble into same situation. I had to change it like this which might not be the right way: 
messages is the base object array which the adapter references to.

```
messages.add("From: " + new_message.getFrom().toString());
messages.add(new_message.getBody());

mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
   myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
```

Comment: no its not a right way: `ArrayAdapter#add()` is, just create a simple project and give it a try

Comment: Yea, it works either way because arrayadapter references the message object. But if we want to change some info about the views , using my way,  it might become simple, i believe. We can just change the message(position) and call notifydatachaged. I may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I did not call adapter.add() from the same thread that created the adapter. So try the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myadapter.add(new_message.getFrom().toString());  
        myadapter.add(new_message.getBody());
    }
});
```